# Take time in milliseconds

Tags: c++

I have found the usleep function in unistd.h, and I thought it was useful to wait some time before every action.But I have discovered that the thread just sleeps if it it doesn't receive any signal.For example if I press a button (I'm using OpenGL but the question is more specific about time.h and unistd.h), the thread gets awaken and I'm not getting what I want.
In time.h there is the sleep function that accepts an integer but an integer is too much ( I want to wait 0.3 seconds), so I use usleep.
I ask if there is a function to take time in milliseconds (from any GNU or whatever library).
It should work like time(), but returning milliseconds instead of seconds.Is that possibile?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you don't like about `usleep`? As near as I can tell it does exactly what you want (well, except for being µs instead of ms).

Comment: I don't get the question. Isn't `microtime` what are you looking for?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want a sleep function, but a "getTime in ms" function.Because if the thread sleeps, it could be awakened by some signal (e.g.: I press a key).

Comment: You probably don't want to sleep at all. "OpenGL and sleep" is usually a combination that doesn't go well, since sleep functions guarantee to block a _minimum time or longer_, not a precise time (and under POSIX not even that, in presence of signals!). That said, the plain normal `gettimeofday` function works at millisecond resolution (micro, actually) no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cross-platform function I use:

```
unsigned Util::getTickCount()
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return GetTickCount();
#else
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    return unsigned((tv.tv_sec * 1000) + (tv.tv_usec / 1000));
#endif
}
```

Comment: I need a function like time() but that get ms.

Answer (score 10):

If you have boost you can do it this way:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(2000));
  return 0;
}
```

This simple example, as you can see in the code, sleeps for 2000ms.

Edit:

Ok, I thought I understood the question but then I read the comments and now I'm not so sure anymore.

Perhaps you want to get how many milliseconds that has passed since some point/event? If that is the case then you could do something like:

```
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
  boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(2000));
  boost::chrono::milliseconds ms = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds> (boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
  std::cout << "2000ms sleep took " << ms.count() << "ms " << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

(Please excuse the long lines)